# Gaussian kernel isn't showing up

Tags: matlab, gaussian

```
I = fspecial('gaussian', [11, 11], 2); 
imshow(I);
```

This code was supposed to generate the following `11`x`11` image.

[image]

But, it's not doing so,

[image]

It's totally black.

Why?

How can I generate the above image using `fspecial`?

Comment: try `imshow(I,[])`.

Comment: Or try imagesc(I)

Comment: @anonymous Why dont you a) read the duplicate b) read the documentation